# Add route to my Laravel Vue project not working

Tags: laravel, vue.js, routes

I want to display the route for the pages login and register.

I run the command:

```
npm run watch.
```

And i got the error:

```
"default" is not exported by "node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js", imported by "resources/js/app.js".
```

My code is:

In resocues/js/app.js:

```
import './bootstrap';
window.Vue = require('vue');
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

// Router imported
import{ routes} from './routes';

const router = VueRouter.createRouter({
mode: "history",
routes, // short for `routes: routes`
  
})

const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
router
})
```

In resouces/js/routes.js:

```
let login = require('./components/auth/login.vue').default;
let register = require('./components/auth/register.vue').default;


export const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: login, name: '/' },
    { path: '/register', component: register, name:'register' }
]
```

I added after body

```
\<div id="app"\> and \<router-view\>\</router-view\>
```

So i want to display the page Login (created in compoents/auth/login.vue ) and Register(created in components/auth/register.vue).

What is wrong with my code?

I try to display the login and register page.

Comment: Can you show us the content of login.vue or register.vue?

Comment: Login Page:<template>
  <h1> Login form </h1>
</template>


<script type="text/javascript">


</script>


<style type="text/css">

</style>

Comment: I got also this error: GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/resources/js/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I made another project from a recent tutorial and i got the same error: "default" is not exported by "node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.mjs", imported by "resources/js/app.js".  So i guess the problem is not the code

Comment: And i run npm run dev, and i got the error: GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/css/app.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you. To resolve it, I checked file ""node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js" and there isn't `export default` in this file but is something like that: `export { NavigationFailureType, RouterLink, ... };`. Hence solution looks like that:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import { routes } from '.routes'

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
    routes
})

const app = createApp({})
    .use(router);
    
app.mount('#app');
```